# Based on menu Items: passing variables from one textbox to another to calculate

Tags: vb.net, variables, textbox

Okay, I looked everywhere, and I couldn't find the right terms that matched what I'm looking for. What I'm trying to do is calculate `(add) the "Menu item 1" and "Menu item 2" OR "Menu item 9"` in the **Textbox2 (the bottom textbox)**. But I have it so it's calculating every item. Is there a way to catch or grab the variables that end up in **Textbox1 (top textbox) and calculate it in the Textbox2**, instead of calculating ALL of them? Each menu item has it's own price, and  I already know how to calculate it with the sales tax. After all, 10 and 9 bucks doesn't add up to 53, does it? I think I did well in 3rd grade math.

Comment: Sorry, but this is very confusing. Could you maybe add an example to illustrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry. I have 9 menu items on the form. They each have their own button, and I have defined them each with their own price. I press two of those buttons (any of them), and the end result is the sum of ALL nine menu items, instead of the two that I pressed the button for. How do I avoid the sum of all nine menu items and instead get the items that have been entered? Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Show us the method that do `Sum` for all the textboxes.

Comment: There is only two textboxes, but here is the code I'm using:                dectotal = decMenu1 + decMenu2 + decMenu3
        decresult = dectotal * dectax
        decsubtotal = dectotal + decresult
        TextBox2.Text = decsubtotal.ToString("C2")

Comment: I have a screenshot, but I'm not allowed to post pictures yet.

Comment: post somewhere else and share the link with us.

Comment: Let me know if this is good enough. I did another, in case this one isn't.

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/126478694@N07/14764243675/lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1
  'Add a CheckedListBox, a TextBox, and a Button to the form

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Set up the menu
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(New MenuItem("Apples", 1D))
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(New MenuItem("Bananas", 1.1D))
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(New MenuItem("Cucumbers", 0.56D))
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(New MenuItem("Daffodils", 0.1D))
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Add up the total
    Dim decTotal As Decimal
    For Each item As MenuItem In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
      decTotal += item.Price
    Next item
    'display the total
    TextBox1.Text = "Total = " & decTotal.ToString("C")
  End Sub

  ''' <summary>
  ''' This class defines a food item on the menu
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <remarks></remarks>
  Class MenuItem
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal

    Sub New(d As String, p As Decimal)
      Me.Description = d
      Me.Price = p
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
      Return Description & " (" & Price.ToString("C") & ")" 'This is what we see in the checkedlistbox
    End Function
  End Class
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I gotta ask though - do I really need a checkedlistbox? I can see how that can be easier, though. Thanks.

Comment: I've posted another, simpler, answer that just uses buttons

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your problem is appears to be here:

```
 dectotal = decMenu1 + decMenu2 + decMenu3
```

`dectotal` should not add up everything directly it should add on conditional basis.

e.g.,  ( pseudocode )

```
dectotal = 0

if(menu1.selected) then dectotal += decMenu1 

if(menu2.selected) then dectotal += decMenu2 

if(menu3.selected) then dectotal += decMenu3 

Debug.Print(dectotal)
```

**EDIT**

Try with `ArrayList` or `List(of Decimal)`

```
1) Declare a class variable of type one of them defined above.
2) In each button's handler (menu1,......, menu9) add the corresponding value to arraylist.
   e.g., menu1 has price 5$, menu2 has price 3$,..... menu 9 has price 7$.
   If Menu9 is pressed, in its event handler, 7 will be added to arraylist.
3) When you calculate and press calculate button, iterate on arraylist items and add up all vales to your `dectotal`.
4) Don;t forget to `clear` arraylist at this point.
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure how to write the If-Else condition. It's more something like: If(decmenu1.displays) then dectotal += decMenu1.

Comment: ...which what I just typed above doesn't make enough sense (with the If-Else statement).

Comment: And the arraylist can be in the module, correct? I have all the menu prices listed in the module.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1
  Private mdecTotal As Decimal 'running total

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text &= vbCrLf & "Apple $1.00"
    mdecTotal += 1
    TextBox2.Text = "Total " & mdecTotal.ToString("C")
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Text &= vbCrLf & "Banana $2.00"
    mdecTotal += 2 '$2
    TextBox2.Text = "Total " & mdecTotal.ToString("C")
  End Sub
  '...you get the idea...


  Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    '"Clear" button - clear the total
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    mdecTotal = 0D
    TextBox2.Text = "Total " & mdecTotal.ToString("C")
  End Sub
End Class
```